# Protractor and $http.post

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, http-post, protractor

I have simple app where i can add conversations(Q/A). I have written test for it -

```
describe('New Survey:', function() {
  it('should be added', function() {
    browser.get('http://127.0.0.1:8090/#/newConversation');
    //picking a user
    element.all(by.css('.form-control')).get(5).click();
    element(by.model('vm.user')).sendKeys('test');
    element(by.repeater('user in vm.users').row(6)).click();
//push some answers
    var inputs = element.all(by.css('.form-control.validated')).each(function(element,index){
      element.sendKeys('test answer');
    });
     //and send it
    element(by.id('submit')).click();
    element(by.css('.confirm')).click()
          browser.waitForAngular();
  });
});
```

after clicking `.confirm` button 
this  method is called

```
this.saveSurvey = function(conv) {
        return $http.post('/conv', conv);
    };
```

but protractor does not wait until its done so no conversation is actually sent to server how could i make it to wait until post is done?

Comment: Do you get any response back from the server when you send a post request to it?

Comment: it looks like i dont ,what can be the reason?

Comment: Its the server which has to respond. If at all its not sending any response, then all you can do is wait for few seconds explicitly or if there is an element that changes on completion of the post request (like a success notification, or a row of text added somewhere, etc), you can wait for that to happen.

Comment: adding `browser.pause()` before clicking the `.confirm` helps but i dont wanna use it in that way

Comment: `browser.pause()` is used for debugging the code. Did you try giving explicit waits or wait until the click is completed by asserting its promise?

Comment: I think you have to add some expectations to the test, because now it actually has nothing to assert and quits right away.

Comment: I know michael, but i cant add it if i cant even add conversation, i dont know explanation for this but as i mentioned `browser.pause()` in right place invoke post without pausing it looks like post is not invoked at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wait for the `click()` function to execute and your post request to be sent by waiting for its promise to be returned. Here's how -

```
element(by.id('submit')).click().then(function(){
    element(by.css('.confirm')).click().then(function(){
        browser.sleep(2000);
        //If your server returns a response in some way that the conversation is saved, you can verify it here.
    });
});
```

Hope it helps.